# Java 3D Graphics using Applet and in built libraries only

Tags: java, graphics, 3d, applet

I want to do Java 3D Graphics without using external libraries to develop a game applet. Sorry I am not that experienced with Graphics and so I am not sure how hard it would be to do it by myself

Comment: First, don't use applets; they're obsolete.

Comment: Java doesn't have a inbuilt 3D library, except for JavaFX, which means you probably don't want to use applets...

Comment: Makes sense... so there is no way to do it without importing external libraries I take it? (when I say do it, now I mean making it an applet or not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer to your question is that you're thinking about it a bit sideways: you shouldn't be using an applet (they're dead), and you shouldn't try to do it all by yourself without any libraries.

I'd personally recommend [Processing](https://processing.org/) for beginners or [libGDX](https://github.com/libGDX/libGDX) for more experienced users. They both allow you to do 3D, and they both allow you to deploy as JavaScript- which is better than applets.

If you really, really, **really** want to try to do this without any libraries, then you'll have to do all the 3D math and whatnot yourself, then do the drawing in Java2D. A very basic example of getting started is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/), but like I said, you're on your own to do all the conversions from 3D world space to 2D drawing space.

Any sane person would use something like OpenGL instead, which you can find Java wrappers for- JOGL is a pretty basic wrapper (so if your goal is to get "close to the metal" then this might be your best bet), LWJGL provides a few extra features for game development, and the already-mentioned libGDX is built on top of LWJGL.

If you're afraid of using libraries because you think they're too complicated, let me tell you that doing 3D stuff without a library is even more complicated.